# Why does 10.0/3 return 3.3333333333333335?

Tags: ruby, floating

Why does `10.0/3` return `3.3333333333333335`? It does not seem correct, does it? Is it a bug?

```
10.0/3
# => 3.3333333333333335
```

Comment: This isn't Ruby specific. Most languages map a float or double type onto the machine's native floats/doubles

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, this is how floating point operations work. One should not care about [mantissa](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mantissa.html) too much, while

```
10.0 / 3.0 * 3.0 == 10.0
#⇒ true
```

Answer (score 0):

Float objects represent inexact real numbers using the native architecture's double-precision floating point representation.

If you look at the Ruby docs, you'll see that float is double precision and is considered an approximate number.http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html

Floating point has a different arithmetic and is an inexact number. You should know its esoteric system. See the following:

http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

You could perform a `round` on the division to get a more accurate answer.

```
(10.0/3).round(5)
```

Comment: How can `round` give a precise answer? It cuts off information.

Comment: I believe the precision in the above case is only accurate up to 15 or 16 digits. That's why you see the trailing 5.

Comment: The original had the error less than 10^(-15) * 2. Rounding it at a higher digit 10^(-5) makes the error even larger.

Comment: Not true. I get 0.33333. There are no 5s in the result

Comment: Of course you get that result. Of course it is true.